# jquery ajax responses are mixed up

Tags: jquery, ajax, response, mixed

I have two ajax calls in one page as below:

```js
  $("#generate_rule").click(function(){
   alert("req-gen");
   var valid = $("#rule_setup").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
     $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "ajax_ops.php",
      data: $("#rule_setup").serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
       alert("res-gen");

      }
     });
    }
   });
  });
  
  $("#save").click(function(){
   alert("req-save");
   var valid = $("#rule_setup").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
     $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "ajax_ops.php",
      data: $("#rule_setup").serialize(),
      success: function(response) { 
       alert("res-save");
      }
     });    
    }
   }); 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When I fire either of these ajax functions first time, they works fine. If I fire one function first and the other one next, ajax response always received by the function fired first. Here's the order of alerts are fired:

Click on the "save" button
1. req-save
2. res-save

Click on the "Generate Rules" button
1. req-gen
2. res-save

Wondering what causing this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved!

This was causing due to incorrect use of form validator usage. "submitHandler:" was firing when the form was submitted through either of the functions.

I replaced the line:

```
 var valid = $("#rule_setup").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
            //Submit ajax here
            }
 });
```

with

```
        var validator = $( "#rule_setup" ).validate();
        var valid = validator.form();
        if (valid){
          //Submit ajax here
        }
```